# Can't install IIS7 and ASP.NET 3.5 on Win7 64-bit

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-3.5, windows-7-x64

Using Win7 32-bit for 3 months and didn't have problem with developing any .NET-based applications including ASP.NET apps.

Just upgraded my laptop's RAM 3 days ago and switched to 64-bit version of Win7.

When I'm working on installing IIS7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, there's an error about not all features were installed for some unknown reason.

When I try to register ASP.NET using `aspnet_regiis -ir` in `c:\Windows\Microsft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\`, a dialog box shows with this error message:

> "Operation failed with 0x80070643" and after I close the dialog box, another error message on the console command shows with this message: "An error has occurred: 0x80004005 Unspecified error".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and I did everything found on the internet but nothing was useful
eventually I was able to solve it by using the following:
note: do it on your own risk
Add the following to you registry only if the doesn't exist (in my case they didn't exist):

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727\Names]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727\Performance]
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64\Names]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64\Performance]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727\Names]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727\Performance]

try installing asp.net 64 bit after that

Comment: In my case the ASP.NET_64 entries were missing. Adding them resolved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Configure IIS to run in 32 bit mode (assuming your apps are 32 bit mode, since that's what you originally developed on).

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/

Try running aspnet_regiis after that is done. Use the 32 bit version of aspnet_regiis.

Comment: Did this and I still get the same error as the orginial poster.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old post, but I thought I'd share what I did to solve this problem on my machine running Windows 7 64-bit.

While IIS was installed on my computer, the ASP.NET features were not enabled.
 
To enable ASP.NET do the following:

Navigate to the **Turn Windows features on or off** dialog.  It's located under 
**Control Panel** --> **Programs and Features**. 
*Note:* Typing 'features' in the Start Menu search will also get you there.

When the **Turn Windows features on or off** dialog appears, navigate to 
 **World Wide Web Services** --> **Application Development Features** 
and make sure **ASP.NET** is checked.

Once this was done the **aspnet_regiis -ir** command worked perfectly and I could run and debug ASP.NET apps on my machine.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

set IIS to run in 32 bit mode

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/

Try running aspnet_regiis after that is done. Use the 32 bit version of aspnet_regiis.

[بریده جراید](http://www.asrepooya.com/fa/projects/bulletin.aspx)